# Return alphanumeric values as id in postgresql

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql, php-pgsql

I have table called tickets with p.k. id and ticket number (i.e. TK0001)

I am using a laravel and for some reason I am required to get the ticket_number as id in response.

Below is my query

> SELECT CAST(ticket_number as varchar) as id from
> tickets.

Below is my response

```
{
"status": 200,
    "data": {
        "current_page": 1,
        "data": [
            {
                "id": 0
            },
            {
                "id": 0
            }
        ],
        "first_page_url": "http://localhost:8000/dm/v2/report/preview/data?page=1",
        "from": 1,
        "last_page": 1,
        "last_page_url": "http://localhost:8000/dm/v2/report/preview/data?page=1",
        "next_page_url": null,
        "path": "http://localhost:8000/dm/v2/report/preview/data",
        "per_page": 100,
        "prev_page_url": null,
        "to": 2,
        "total": 2
    }
}
```

If you see it's returning me `"id": 0`
But it returns me the ticket number when using the alias name different like ids.

Here are the data from my table

```
id       ticket_number
22021   "TK33412"
22022   "TK15961"
22023   "TK15840"
22024   "TK33413"
22025   "TK33416"
22026   "TK33415"
```

here is my query

```
$mainSelect = "CAST(ticket_number as varchar) as id ";
$query = \App\Models\DM\LeadsTickets::selectRaw($mainSelect);
$queryResponse = $query->paginate($perPage , $page);
return $queryResponse;
```

Comment: Please include sample table data, along with the raw Postgres query you are trying to run.

Comment: There is something wrong in the code that you didn't share.

Comment: @FrankHeikens , added the query

Comment: It is probably just whatever JSON encoder you are using not checking against the postgresql type information and being "clever" instead. It sees digits and gives you a number.

Comment: @RichardHuxton, possible ..  But problem is when it execute this query in  pgsql  it works , but using the laravel it getting the data as 0 when i use the alias id

Comment: should `selectRaw` not be prefixed by a select first? Give `LeadsTickets::select("*")->selectRaw($mainSelect);` a try and tell me what it does.

Comment: @RichardHuxton,, You are right i guess,,  It works fine until i use `return response()->json($queryResponse);`  so it's the encode of laravel which is smart